# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error when updating a table

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim str As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=..\VisitorPass.accdb"
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "Update Visitor set [password]='" & txtPassword.Text & "',FirstName='" & txtFirstName.Text & "',LastName='" & txtLastName.Text & "',Gender='" & txtGender.Text & "',MobileNo='" & txtMobileNO.Text & "',DateOfBirth='" & txtDateOfBirth.Text & "',VisitorAddress='" & txtVisitorAddress.Text & "'where ID='" & lblID2.Text & "'"
    con = New OleDbConnection(str)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim obj1 As New VisitorProfile
    obj1.StringPass = txtName.Text
    MsgBox("profile is updated")
    obj1.Show()
    con.Close()
    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Before doing any attempt to help, please add to your question the value of `str` and the type of the columns you are updating.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one field in your criteria expression, `Id`. I'd suspect instead of being Text it's actually an Integer. So remove the quotes: (*also add in a space between the single quote and where).*

```
"' where ID=" & lblID2.Text & "
```

However this leaves you open to an sql injection attack so you should parameterize your query.